# Serializar XML para REST API com Acentuação Correta

Tags: java, json, serialização, jaxb

Estou criando um pequeno serviço REST API somente leitura em um sistema de um cliente. Ele usa Spring MVC para atender às requisições e o objetivo de cada requisição é devolver um JSON com determinadas informações para outro sistema que estou escrevendo.

Para gerar o JSON, estou usando JAXB + Jettison. A criação e devolução do objeto é mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
package com.empresa.projeto.financeiro;

import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter;

import org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.Configuration;
import org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedNamespaceConvention;
import org.codehaus.jettison.mapped.MappedXMLStreamWriter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.empresa.projeto.domain.Lancamento;
import com.empresa.projeto.financeiro.marshalling.JSONLancamento;
import com.empresa.projeto.financeiro.marshalling.JSONLancamentos;
import com.empresa.projeto.service.LancamentoService;

@Controller
public class Lancamentos {
    @Autowired private LancamentoService lancamentoService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/lancamentos/teste", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getLancamentos(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Calendar dataInicial = Calendar.getInstance();

        try {
            dataInicial.setTime(df.parse(req.getParameter("data_inicial")));
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();   
        }

        Calendar dataFinal = Calendar.getInstance();

        try {
            dataFinal.setTime(df.parse(req.getParameter("data_final")));
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();   
        }

        ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();

        JAXBContext jbc = JAXBContext.newInstance(JSONLancamentos.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jbc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        MappedNamespaceConvention con = new MappedNamespaceConvention(config);
        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
        XMLStreamWriter xmlStreamWriter = new MappedXMLStreamWriter(con, writer);

        JSONLancamentos lancamentos = new JSONLancamentos();

        List<Lancamento> lancamentosOriginais = lancamentoService.selecionarLancamentos(dataInicial, dataFinal);

        for (Lancamento lancOriginal: lancamentosOriginais) {
            JSONLancamento lancamento = new JSONLancamento();

            lancamento.setCategoria(lancOriginal.getCategoria());
            lancamento.setData(lancOriginal.getData());
            lancamento.setDias(lancOriginal.getDias());
            lancamento.setEmpresa(lancOriginal.getEmpresa().getNome());
            lancamento.setId(lancOriginal.getId());
            lancamento.setMotivo(lancOriginal.getMotivo());
            lancamento.setServico(lancOriginal.getServico());
            lancamento.setStatus(lancOriginal.getStatus());
            lancamento.setTipo(lancOriginal.getTipo());
            lancamento.setValor(lancOriginal.getValor());

            lancamentos.getLancamentos().add(lancamento);
        }

        marshaller.marshal(lancamentos, xmlStreamWriter);
    }
}
```

As classes que descrevem a serialização estão abaixo:

### JSONLancamentos.java

```
package com.empresa.projeto.financeiro.marshalling;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement (name="listagemlancamentos")
public class JSONLancamentos {

    private List<JSONLancamento> lancamentos;

    @XmlElement(name="lancamentos")
    public List<JSONLancamento> getLancamentos() {
        if (lancamentos == null) {
            lancamentos = new ArrayList<JSONLancamento>();
        }

        return lancamentos;
    }

    public void setLancamentos(List<JSONLancamento> lancamentos) {
        this.lancamentos = lancamentos;
    }
}
```

### JSONLancamento.java

```
package com.empresa.projeto.financeiro.marshalling;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import com.empresa.projeto.domain.Lancamento;

@XmlRootElement(name="lancamento")
public class JSONLancamento {
    private Long id;
    private char status;
    private Date data;
    private BigDecimal valor;
    private String motivo;
    private String empresa;
    private String localidade;
    private char servico;
    private char tipo;
    private char categoria;
    private boolean faturar = true;
    private int dias = 0;

    private String categoriaExtenso;

    @XmlElement
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public char getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(char status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    ...
}
```

O problema é que as propriedades que retornam `String` estão sendo serializadas com a acentuação errada. Caracteres como "ã", "ó" e "é" não aparecem corretamente no resultado.

Há alguma configuração que deve ser feita para que este resultado seja devolvido com a codificação correta?

Os fontes são todos em UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para funcionar, precisei trocar o serializador. O Jettison não funcionou de jeito algum. Mudei para o Jackson e funcionou:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonSerialize.Inclusion;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/* Outros imports relativos ao projeto em si */

@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/lancamentos/teste2", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json; charset=UTF-8" })
public void getLancamentos2(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws Exception {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Calendar dataInicial = Calendar.getInstance();

    try {
        dataInicial.setTime(df.parse(req.getParameter("data_inicial")));
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    Calendar dataFinal = Calendar.getInstance();

    try {
        dataFinal.setTime(df.parse(req.getParameter("data_final")));
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();

    JSONLancamentos lancamentos = new JSONLancamentos();

    List<Lancamento> lancamentosOriginais = lancamentoService
            .selecionarLancamentos(dataInicial, dataFinal);

    for (Lancamento lancOriginal : lancamentosOriginais) {
        JSONLancamento lancamento = new JSONLancamento();

        lancamento.setCategoria(lancOriginal.getCategoria());
        lancamento.setData(lancOriginal.getData());
        lancamento.setDias(lancOriginal.getDias());
        lancamento.setEmpresa(lancOriginal.getEmpresa().getNome());
        lancamento.setId(lancOriginal.getId());
        lancamento.setMotivo(lancOriginal.getMotivo());
        lancamento.setServico(lancOriginal.getServico());
        lancamento.setStatus(lancOriginal.getStatus());
        lancamento.setTipo(lancOriginal.getTipo());
        lancamento.setValor(lancOriginal.getValor());
        lancamento.setEmpresaId(lancOriginal.getEmpresa().getId());

        lancamentos.getLancamentos().add(lancamento);
    }

    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.ALWAYS);
    mapper.writeValue(out, lancamentos);
}
```

### pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Cara eu já vi problema parecido com o seu usando `Jaxb` sobre acentuação, o que eu indiquei para pessoa era passar os `bytes` e verificar qual `charset` estava sendo usado antes, e olha que ela setava na mão o `UTF-8`, antes de parsear a xml.

Passei este classe util para a pessoa. E deu certo.

```
public class CharsetUtil {

    public static Charset detectCharset(File file) {

        String[] charsets = { "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1"};

        for (String charsetName : charsets) {

            if (detectCharset(file, Charset.forName(charsetName))) {
                return Charset.forName(charsetName);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static boolean detectCharset(File file, Charset charset) {

        try (BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file))) {

            CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
            decoder.reset();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
            boolean identified = false;

            while ((input.read(buffer) != -1) && (!identified)) {
                identified = identify(buffer, decoder);
            }

            return identified;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            return false;
        }
    }

    private static boolean identify(byte[] bytes, CharsetDecoder decoder) {

        try {
            decoder.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes));
        } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: Vou testar mais tarde, mas note que eu não tenho exatamente um arquivo: tenho um `XMLStreamWriter` que passar por um `Marshaller`. O que preciso fazer pra ocorrer essa conversão usando o `XMLStreamWriter`?

Comment: Eu postei de exemplo o código, como disse eu não trabalhei com isso propriamente, só unmarshall, mas pegue os bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Se você vai retornar o JSON no endpoint /lancamentos/test (apesar de estar void), existe um atributo do @RequestMapping que é o "produces":

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lancamentos/teste", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces={"application/json; charset=UTF-8"})
```

Comment: Fiz os testes aqui com o `produces` e o resultado infelizmente foi o mesmo.